# setting up django for deployment

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django app I've split the settings.py and put in a settings folder. Now before I run my server, I must first this

`set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=src.settings.dev`

How can I make the above command to be automatic so I don't have type it every time before running the server .thanks

Answer (score 0):

edit the below line in your manage.py for example in my case was
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'src.settings.dev')`